# Getting value from nested NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, html-parsing, nsdictionary

After trying 100 attempts at this im resorting to SO.

I have this output in dictionary from an html parser using libxml2

```
 {
        nodeChildArray =             (
                            {
                nodeAttributeArray =                     (
                                            {
                        attributeName = class;
                        nodeContent = imgContainer;
                    }
                );
                nodeChildArray =                     (
                                            {
                        nodeAttributeArray =                             (
                                                            {
                                attributeName = src;
                                nodeContent = "/~/media/Images/Image 2.ashx";
                            },
                                                            {
                                attributeName = alt;
                                nodeContent = "Image 2";
                            },
                                                            {
                                attributeName = width;
                                nodeContent = 60;
                            },
                                                            {
                                attributeName = height;
                                nodeContent = 112;
                            }
                        );
                        nodeName = img;
                    }
                );
                nodeName = div;
            }
        );
        nodeName = td;
    },
```

I am trying to get the of nodeContent that is /~/media/Images/Image 2.ashx...

Any ideas how should my iteration look like?

Comment: I am also wondering how we can use the method of NSDictionary valueForKeyPath in this case... if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code for access should look like

```
[[[nodeChildArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"nodeContent"];
```

i am using 0 you can get it with from a loop runs upto count of array.

make sure your array having objects or make a proper if else structure and break this into separate statements. then it should look like

```
if([nodeChildArray count] >0)
{
array1=[nodeChildArray objectAtIndex:0];  //an array object
if([array1 count]>0)
{
dictionary=[array1 objectAtIndex:0]; //a dictionary
//then you can find the value

id value=[dictionary valueForKey:@"nodeContent"];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have a warning saying NSDictionary may not respond to objectAtIndex. and it also doesnt execute. This is how i tried: NSArray *objData = [self PerformHTMLXPathQuery:responseData queryString:xpathQueryString];
    [responseData release];

 for (NSDictionary *vitamin in objData)
 {
  NSLog(@"%@", [[[vitamin objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"nodeContent"]);

Comment: ok then you having dictionary in array then you can access by valueForKey except objectAtIndex;

Comment: This works, if you're sure of the hierarchy: `[[[dict valueForKey:@"foo"] valueForKey:@"man"] valueForKey:@"chu"]`